# How do the incidents of Ricky getting shot relate to the themes of the show?

Tags: analysis, trailer-park-boys

My memory of the early seasons of *Trailer Park Boys* is hazy, but the frequency of Ricky getting shot seems to be increasing.

Specifically in S10, a bullet lodges in his temporal lobe, and he is only revived by an infusion of weed that jumpstarts his brain. Then, in S11/EP3, he gets shot through the scrotum by his three-year old grandson, [Mo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moe_Howard), and twice more in the finale, in the hand and leg respectively.

But how do these [running gags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_gag) relate to underlying themes explored on the show?  What is the symbolism behind the specific incidents?

Answer (score -1):

Certainly the incident involving Mo is an re-enactment of [Cronus' castration of his father, Ouranos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cronus#Mythology). Although it is not literal in TPB, the symbolism is the same. (Skipping a generation in TPB, i.e. Ricky is Mo's grandfather, is not really an issue because Mo's father is Jacob, who doesn't really count.)

It's a metaphor for Ricky having "passed the torch" in terms of fathering offspring.  Mo is saying "the days of your rule are at an end, and the new generation will replace you.